# Problems with UIButton selected

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button

I have a button referenced in the *.h file as Outlet

I call a Function if button is pressed down:

```
- (IBAction) sendButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [sendButton setSelected:YES];
    [sendButton setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Then do some other stuff with uploading.

The problem is that the button is not marked as selected immediately. 
The code runs throw the uploading and then maybe for a second it is selected.

What can I do do show the button.selected before the other code stuff performs?

Comment: Are you sure your uploading process does not block main thread for that second?

Comment: I have add a breakpoint before I start the upload and it changes nothing. so I think it is unindependent from upload. If I put the upload into the background it takes 10 seconds longer as in the main que